# kinetic.js multiple click events in a loop but only registers the last one

Tags: javascript, html, audio, canvas, kineticjs

I have this code:

```
var load_image = function( src ){
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = src;
    return img;
};

var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({container: 'main', width: 640, height: 480});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

var setup = {
    kick : {
        sound: 'kick',
        image_config : {
            image : load_image( '/images/bass.png' ),
            x : 250,
            y : 50
        }
    },
    snare : {
        sound: 'snare',
        image_config : {
            image : load_image( '/images/snare.png' ),
            x : 220,
            y : 220
        }
    },
    hats : {
        sound: 'hats',
        image_config : {
            image : load_image( '/images/hi-hat.png' ),
            x : 140,
            y : 150
        }
    }
};

var img;

for ( name in setup )
{
    img = new Kinetic.Image( setup[name].image_config );

    img.on('click', function()
    {
        soundManager.play( setup[name].sound );
    });

    img.createImageHitRegion(function()
    {
        layer.drawHit();
    },true);

    layer.add(img);
}

stage.add(layer);
```

Here's the problem. For each attribute in the setup object, i want to add a click event to it. (shown above)

```
img.on('click', function()
{
    soundManager.play( setup[name].sound );
});
```

so when the kick is kicked, it triggers the kick sound, when the snare is clicked it triggers the snare sound etc etc... The sound attribute in each setup attribute describes the sound that should be played.

The problem is, all click events trigger the 'hats' sound. I figured out that it is because the 'hats' attribute is the LAST one in the setup object.

What am i doing wrong? Is it because of the callback?

If you visit [here](http://id.a3mediauk.com/v2/) you will see an example.

Also, in the example, if you double click, it only triggers the sound once, when it should trigger twice! whats up with that?

Comment: also, could you put this code in a jsfiddle maybe? I know that you have your example online, but a jsfiddle would help out.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's this: move the var from outside the for loop to inside the for loop. Because `var img` makes this a single variable which you were redefining each time the loop ran, so it just kept the last setting.

Instead, you need to add some local scope so that the function does not re-write the variable each time the loop runs.
try creating a local variable inside the loop like below

```
for ( name in setup )
{
    var newImg = new Kinetic.Image( setup[name].image_config );

    newImg.on('click', function()    
    {
        soundManager.play( setup[name].sound );
    });

    newImg.createImageHitRegion(function()
    {
        layer.drawHit();
    },true);

    layer.add(newImg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Rather than referencing `setup[name].sound` in the click callback event, I set the image name attribute to the name, and then fetched the name using the mouse event passed to the function like so:

var img;

```
for ( name in setup )
{
    img = new Kinetic.Image( setup[name].image_config );

    img.attrs.name = name;

    img.on('click', function(i)
    {
        soundManager.play( i.shape.attrs.name );
    });

    img.createImageHitRegion(function()
    {
       layer.drawHit();
    },true);

    layer.add(img);
}
```

Comment: Could you select your answer as the correct one so that this is no longer marked as an unanswered question?